# Can someone help me?

Tags: probability

A five-digit number is chosen at random from all possible five-digit numbers. Find the probability that the number is not divisible by every element of {1,2,3,4,5,6}

I have tried but I seem to be confused. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Should $1$ be excluded?

Comment: It could be, I think.

Comment: **Hint:** You need the $\text{least common multiple}$ of 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. Can you go on?

Answer (score 2):

If a number is divisible by **every** number from 1 to 6, it must be a multiple of

$$lcm(1,2,3,4,5,6)=2^2\cdot3\cdot5=60$$

Now just count the multiples of 60 that are at least 10000 and at most 99999.